# Asking For Career Advice in Tech

Tags: career-development, technology, software-engineering, web

**Hello Everyone.
I need some career suggestions.**

Due to the current enhancement in AI, starters like me are confused, will there be a demand for fresher web developers after 1 year?

Should I continue to learn web development with the preferred technology I mentioned above, or should I try other technologies, how can I use current AI to enforce my understanding?

Finally, I want to be a full-stack developer and want to build my ideas into a product before that I have to self-sustain my career, meaning how to be good at full-stack web development first so in future I can pay for my living and further pursuit of becoming full stack engineer.

**My current skill and experience**
70% frontend, 50% backend
Preferred technology JavaScript, react, node, express, relational database.

I am interested in full-stack development, UI /UX, and understanding the brain, mind, and behavior.

**Currently, I lack in.**

1. Programming logic building.
2. Mathematics knowledge is average.

I kindly request your assistance and guidance in navigating this crucial career stage. I would greatly appreciate any advice or suggestions you can provide to help me grow and succeed. Your expertise and insights would be invaluable to me. Thank you!

Comment: "70% frontend, 50% backend" "Mathematics knowledge is average" I am forced to agree with your latter statement.

Comment: @PhilipKendall since you are a software developer do you have any advice on improving programming logic and backend development?

Comment: This is really too broad a question to be answerable in the Stack Exchange format.

Comment: "I lack in Programming logic building." That is a crucial lack. Instead of looking for a development job, you might look in communications of various kinds. The world always needs people who can communicate concepts, document what is being developed, and talk to sales people / customers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're a developer, try using ChatGPT to replace yourself and see how successful you are.

For any task, complete it first, whatever method you use, without ChatGPT.

Next, repeat the same task, but now use ONLY ChatGPT. See how long it takes you to get the prompt to actually spit out the final, working code. Then look at how many prompts you needed and the type of prompts, and ask yourself what the likelihood of a non-developer coming up with all that, without knowing how to code.

You'll find out that ChatGPT is very, very far from taking away your job.

My experience with ChatGPT is that it is great for generating ideas and explore things you have never done. It is not even close to being able to generate real, production code. Heck, just the other day, it referenced proposal specification and wrote a program for me based on that. Proposal was HTML picture-in-picture on non-video elements. The code looked legit, but none of it was valid code. I was able to generate a solution on my own, but then found out that some browsers allow only a single instance of PIP (Chrome), and I needed at least 2, so that idea was a deadend.

Why couldn't ChatGPT tell me THAT (limitations of PIP) and asked me how many I need? A real developer consultant would've been able to give me the answer I needed and not waste hours of my time.

If anything, ChatGPT actually widens the gap between non-developer and developer, because ChatGPT can now generate so many more ideas for you to explore. An untrained person wouldn't be able to filter through the noise, but a developer could, and actually learn from the legit content generated, discarding all the useless noise that comes with it.

Comment: do you have any advice on improving programming logic and backend? Any resource and advice would be valuable.

Comment: @kshitizghimire You definitely can use ChatGPT for that question. Try it out.

Answer (score 4):

General advice-  whenever you hear a new technology get a lot of hype, be very dubious.  The more hype it gets with less solid results, be even more dubious.  AI is a perfect example of this, lots of hype and very little in the way of results.  Right now its at the level of being a mediocre alternative to google, except with a good chance it will just make up an answer if it doesn't have a real one, and it only gives one result rather than the dozens google would.  This is about the 20th technology that would eliminate programming I've seen in my career.  Strangely, there's more professional programmers than ever.

Comment: thanks you for the advice.